# Bitcoin RPC SSL error

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

I recently tried running Bitcoin-QT as a server with SSL enabled, but when I was testing the connection, with this [command](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon):

```
openssl s_client -connect 111.11.111.111:8332
```

I got this error:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
4308:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-35.1/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:182:
```

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this problem and how should I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of mocking about with this problem, I figured the certificate files were in a wrong folder. As I was running Bitcoin on testnet, the directory in which it looks for certificates is different, than on the main net. On the other hand, it loads the Bitcoin.conf from the same place...

The folder bitcoin looks for the certificate in is the folder containing wallet.dat, which for testnet is in .bitcoin/testnet/ folder

Comment: Interesting edit... I thought @Community was a process not a real human user